# How to get millis of timestamp since 1970 UTC in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which one of the columns is of type `TIMESTAMP(6)`.

How do I get the milliseconds of the column's data since `1970 UTC`?

Comment: Do you want to take into account leap seconds? [Oracle doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31136211/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select (cast(your_column as date) - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60 from your_table;
```

Comment: This is seconds since 1970 not milliseconds. For milliseconds you want: `SELECT (CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS DATE) - DATE '1970-01-01')*24*60*60*1000 + MOD( EXTRACT( SECOND FROM SYSTIMESTAMP ), 1 ) * 1000 FROM DUAL`

Comment: Reformatting previous comment into: `SELECT ((TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'MI') - DATE '1970-01-01') * 86400 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) * 1000 FROM DUAL`

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  MY_TS as orig
  , extract(day from (MY_TS-to_timestamp_tz('01-01-70 0', 'DD-MM-RR TZH')))*1000*60*60*24
  + extract(hour from (MY_TS-to_timestamp_tz('01-01-70 0', 'DD-MM-RR TZH')))*1000*60*60
  + extract(minute from (MY_TS-to_timestamp_tz('01-01-70 0', 'DD-MM-RR TZH')))*1000*60
  + extract(second from (MY_TS-to_timestamp_tz('01-01-70 0', 'DD-MM-RR TZH')))*1000
    as millis
from MY_TABLE;
```

Comment: Please notice that if you timestamp has a different timezone than the client, you'd probably want to specify what it is. For that, replace `MY_TS` with `FROM_TZ(MY_TS, 'PST')`

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account leap seconds:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eef06/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION milliseconds_Since_1970(
  datetime TIMESTAMP
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
AS
  diff   INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(9) := datetime - TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
  millis NUMBER(38,0) := EXTRACT( DAY    FROM diff ) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                       + EXTRACT( HOUR   FROM diff )      * 60 * 60 * 1000
                       + EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM diff )           * 60 * 1000
                       + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM diff )                * 1000;
  leap_seconds SYS.ODCIDATELIST := SYS.ODCIDATELIST(
    DATE '1972-07-01',
    DATE '1973-01-01',
    DATE '1974-01-01',
    DATE '1975-01-01',
    DATE '1976-01-01',
    DATE '1977-01-01',
    DATE '1978-01-01',
    DATE '1979-01-01',
    DATE '1980-01-01',
    DATE '1981-07-01',
    DATE '1982-07-01',
    DATE '1983-07-01',
    DATE '1985-07-01',
    DATE '1988-01-01',
    DATE '1990-01-01',
    DATE '1991-01-01',
    DATE '1992-07-01',
    DATE '1993-07-01',
    DATE '1994-07-01',
    DATE '1996-01-01',
    DATE '1997-07-01',
    DATE '1999-01-01',
    DATE '2006-01-01',
    DATE '2009-01-01',
    DATE '2012-07-01',
    DATE '2015-07-01',
    DATE '2017-01-01'
  );
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. leap_seconds.COUNT LOOP
    IF datetime < leap_seconds(i) THEN
      RETURN millis;
    END IF;
    millis := millis + 1000;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN millis;
END;
//
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT milliseconds_Since_1970( TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' ) AS "MS 1970-01-01 00:00:00",
       milliseconds_Since_1970( TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:01:00' ) AS "MS 1970-01-01 00:01:00",
       milliseconds_Since_1970( TIMESTAMP '1972-06-30 23:59:59' ) AS "MS 1972-06-30 23:59:59",
       milliseconds_Since_1970( TIMESTAMP '1972-07-01 00:00:00' ) AS "MS 1972-07-01 00:00:00"
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eef06/2/0)**:

```
| MS 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | MS 1970-01-01 00:01:00 | MS 1972-06-30 23:59:59 | MS 1972-07-01 00:00:00 |
|------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|
|                      0 |                  60000 |            78796799000 |            78796801000 |
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have to say that after working with Oracle for a really short while - this is one of the least user-friendly databases  I've ever seen. Truly baffling that this is not included as system utility function.

Comment: While this formally answers the question, I wonder if what the OP really wanted was [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) where each day is always 86400. In other words: taking leap seconds into account is rarely what people want when they ask  "how to get (milli)seconds since epoch" question. What they really want is Unix Time. Just my experience.

Comment: besides most probably not what the OP really wanted, doesn't feel very future-proof. (well, actually not even past-proof by now...). Might worth a mention

Answer (score 1):

I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63597872/6866545) some methods to convert timestamp to nanoseconds and nanoseconds to timestamp. These methods are not affected by time zones and have a nanosecond precision.

You just need to adjust it to get milliseconds instead of nanoseconds.

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(DAY FROM (
    SYSTIMESTAMP --Replace line with desired timestamp --Maximum value: TIMESTAMP '3871-04-29 10:39:59.999999999 UTC'
- TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC') * 24 * 60) * 60 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM
    SYSTIMESTAMP --Replace line with desired timestamp
)) *  1000 AS MILLIS FROM DUAL;

MILLIS
1598434427263.027
```