# Get same result with Oracle SQL Query as with JS date.now() method

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle, datetime-format

Is there a quick way to get the exact same result when using date.now() method (returns milliseconds that elapsed since 1970-01-01) in JS via SQL select statement?

I guess this could be the start:

`select current_timestamp from dual;`

...but from that point on, I got stuck with getting the format as mentioned above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get millis of timestamp since 1970 UTC in Oracle SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652232/how-to-get-millis-of-timestamp-since-1970-utc-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be

```
SQL> SELECT     (CAST (SYSTIMESTAMP AS DATE) - DATE '1970-01-01')
  2           * 24
  3           * 60
  4           * 60
  5           * 1000
  6         + MOD (EXTRACT (SECOND FROM SYSTIMESTAMP), 1) * 1000 result
  7    FROM DUAL;

          RESULT
----------------
   1629124489718

SQL>
```

Comment: @PhilGee -  I don't think this is correct. JS `date.now()` returns milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC. `SYSTIMESTAMP` is the timestamp in the time zone of the database server, which may be different from UTC. Use `systimestamp at time zone 'UTC'` instead.

Comment: @mathguy - Oh, yes - that's right. A fact one shouldn't forget about... like I did ;-) Thank you!